# ELF file headers

Tags: linux, unix, embedded

A quick question about elf file headers, I can't seem to find anything useful on how to add/change fields in the elf header. I'd like to be able to change the magic numbers and to add a build date to the header, and probably a few other things.

As I understand it the linker creates the header information, but I don't see anything in the LD script that refers to it (though i'm new to ld scripts).

I'm using gcc and building for ARM.

thanks!

Updates:

- ok maybe my first question should be: is it possible to create/edit the header file at link time?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't know of linker script commands that can do this, but you can do it post-link using the **objcopy** command.  The **--add-section** option can be used to add a section containing arbitrary data to the ELF file.  If the ELF header doesn't contain the fields you want, just make a new section and add them there.

Answer (score 8):

[This link (teensy elf binary)](http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html) was someone's answer to another question, but it goes into the intricacies of an ELF header in some detail.

Comment: Great! thanks for that, helps me with another question i have also!

Answer (score 4):

You can create an object file with informative fields like a version number and link that file such that they are included in the resulting ELF binary.

### Ident

For example, as part of you build process, you can generate - say - `info.c` that contains one or more `#ident` directives:

```
#ident "Build: 1.2.3 (Halloween)"
#ident "Environment: example.org"
```

Compile it:

```
$ gcc -c info.c
```

Check if the information is included:

```
$ readelf -p .comment info.o
String dump of section '.comment':
  [     1]  Build: 1.2.3 (Halloween)
  [    1a]  Environment: example.org
  [    33]  GCC: (GNU) 7.2.1 20170915 (Red Hat 7.2.1-2)
```

Alternatively, you can use `objdump -s --section .comment info.o`. Note that GCC also writes its own comment, by default.

Check the information after linking an ELF executable:

```
$ gcc -o main main.o info.o
$ readelf -p .comment main 
String dump of section '.comment':
  [     0]  GCC: (GNU) 7.2.1 20170915 (Red Hat 7.2.1-2)
  [    2c]  Build: 1.2.3 (Halloween)
  [    45]  Environment: example.org
```

#### Comment Section

Using `#ident` in a C translation unit is basically equivalent to creating a `.comment` section in an assembler file. Example:

```
$ cat info.s
.section .comment
.string "Build: 1.2.3 (Halloween)"
.string "Environment: example.org"
$ gcc -c info.s
$ readelf -p .comment info.o
String dump of section '.comment':
  [     0]  Build: 1.2.3 (Halloween)
  [    19]  Environment: example.org
```

Using an uncommon section name works, as well (e.g. `.section .blahblah`). But `.comment` is used and understood by other tools. GNU as also understands the `.ident` directive, and this is what GCC translates `#ident` to.

### With Symbols

For data that you also want to access from the ELF executable itself you need to create symbols.

#### Objcopy

Say you want to include some magic bytes stored in a data file:

```
$ cat magic.bin 
2342
```

Convert into a object file with [GNU objcopy](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/objcopy.html):

```
$ objcopy -I binary -O elf64-x86-64 -B i386 \
    --rename-section .data=.rodata,alloc,load,readonly,data,contents \
    magic.bin magic.o
```

Check for the symbols:

```
$ nm  magic.o  
0000000000000005 R _binary_magic_bin_end
0000000000000005 A _binary_magic_bin_size
0000000000000000 R _binary_magic_bin_start
```

Example usage:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

extern const char _binary_magic_bin_start[];
extern const char _binary_magic_bin_end[];
extern const unsigned char _binary_magic_bin_size;
static const size_t magic_bin_size = (uintptr_t) &_binary_magic_bin_size;

int main()
{
  char s[23];
  memcpy(s, _binary_magic_bin_start,
      _binary_magic_bin_end - _binary_magic_bin_start);
  s[magic_bin_size] = 0;
  puts(s);
  return 0;
}
```

Link everything together:

```
$ gcc -g -o main_magic main_magic.c magic.o
```

### GNU ld

[GNU ld](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/index.html) is also able to turn data files into object files using an objcopy compatible naming scheme:

```
$ ld -r -b binary magic.bin -o magic-ld.o
```

Unlike objcopy, it places the symbols into the `.data` instead of the `.rodata` section, though (cf. `objdump -h magic.o`).

#### incbin

In case GNU objcopy isn't available, one can use the [GNU as](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/index.html) [`.incbin` directive](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Incbin.html#Incbin) to create the object file (assemble with `gcc -c incbin.s`):

```
    .section .rodata

    .global _binary_magic_bin_start
    .type _binary_magic_bin_start, @object
_binary_magic_bin_start:
    .incbin "magic.bin"
    .size _binary_magic_bin_start, . - _binary_magic_bin_start

    .global _binary_magic_bin_size
    .type _binary_magic_bin_size, @object
    .set _binary_magic_bin_size, . - _binary_magic_bin_start

    .global _binary_magic_bin_end
    .type _binary_magic_bin_end, @object
    .set _binary_magic_bin_end, _binary_magic_bin_start + _binary_magic_bin_size
    ; an alternate  way to include the size    
    .global _binary_magic_bin_len
    .type _binary_magic_bin_len, @object
    .size _binary_magic_bin_len, 8
_binary_magic_bin_len:
    .quad _binary_magic_bin_size
```

#### xxd

A more portable alternative that doesn't require GNU objcopy nor GNU as is to create an intermediate C file and compile and link that. For example with [xxd](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/xxd/xxd.1.en.html):

```
$ xxd -i magic.bin | sed 's/\(unsigned\)/const \1/' > magic.c
$ gcc -c magic.c
$ nm magic.o
0000000000000000 R magic_bin
0000000000000008 R magic_bin_len
$ cat magic.c
const unsigned char magic_bin[] = {
  0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x32, 0x0a
};
const unsigned int magic_bin_len = 5;
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm fairly sure that a sufficiently complex ld script can do what you want.  However, I have no idea how.

On the other hand, [elfsh](http://elfsh.asgardlabs.org/) can easily do all sorts of manipulations to elf objects, so give it a whirl.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use libmelf, a dead project on freshmeat, but available from LOPI - http://www.ipd.bth.se/ska/lopi.html

Otherwise, you can get the spec and (over)write the header yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this in awhile, but can't you just append arbitrary data to an executable. If you always append fixed-size data it would be trivial to recover anything you append. Variable size wouldn't be much harder. Probably easier than messing w/ elf headers and potentially ruining you executables.

Comment: good idea, i'll probably do a checksum this way, it should be possible to add the build date etc too. However I still really want to know if you can change the elf file header know i've spent so much time looking at it!

Answer (score 0):

In Solaris you can use [elfedit](http://blogs.oracle.com/ali/entry/changing_elf_runpaths) but I think you are really asking solutions for Linux. Linux Is Not UniX :P

Answer (score 0):

I didn't finish the book but iirc [Linkers and Loaders by John Levine](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558604960) had the gory details that you would need to be able to do this.

Answer (score -1):

In Linux Console:

$ man ld

$ ld --verbose

HTH