# Adding section to ELF file

Tags: c, linux, elf

I need to be able to add an arbitrary section to an ELF file. I cannot use GPL code in this program, so BFD is out of the question. I can use libelf/gelf to read sections, but the documentation is fairly sparse for these, and I cannot figure out how to add a section. Does anybody know how to do this? I would rather not write my own ELF code.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There's a few (possibly) related answers in [this question about ELF file headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233358/elf-file-headers).  The accepted answer mentioned using `objcopy` to add sections to an ELF file, and the [BSD bintools](http://wiki.freebsd.org/BSDBintools) claims to have a BSD-licensed implementation of `objcopy` that might suit your needs.

Answer (score 25):

I know this is an old question but i found a working example that helped me to apply it to my project. (In case anyone stumbles upon this question)

taken from [Sourceware Mail Archiv](http://sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2008-06/msg00216.html)

```
$ echo 'int main() { puts ("Hello world"); }' | gcc -x c - -c -o hello.o

$ echo "this is my special data" >mydata

$ objcopy --add-section .mydata=mydata \
          --set-section-flags .mydata=noload,readonly hello.o hello2.o

$ gcc hello2.o -o hello

$ ./hello
Hello world

$ objdump -sj .mydata hello
```

Answer (score 3):

The following links could be useful:

- The tutorial "[libelf by Example](http://sourceforge.net/projects/elftoolchain/files/Documentation/libelf-by-example)" has a chapter on creating new ELF objects.
- The [elftoolchain project](http://elftoolchain.sourceforge.net/) has manual pages describing `libelf`'s API in detail.

Answer (score 2):

have a look at ELFsh, which is now part of the ERESI project
http://www.eresi-project.org/
They have a lot of documentation and cool uses of their tools.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried it (yet) myself but you might look at the function elf_newscn in libelf