# how to map file during coredump analyse

Tags: gdb, memory-mapped-files, coredump

I have to analyze a coredump.
Most data of my process is contained in a mapped file.
When I want to access to that data, `gdb` says that it cannot access that data because it hasn't mapped the file.
Do you know how to make `gdb` map that file in order to have access to data.

Comment: Can you give some more details?  Typically the core file is under *nix OS's will have the full memory space of the process.  Perhaps you can create a small example?

Comment: Hello, core file doesn't have full memory space in my case. Mapped file belongs to virtual memory of the process. Core file doesn't contain t these segments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to make gdb map that file in order to have access to data.

I don't believe GDB has any commands to do that.

What you could do is wrap the data file into an object file, and use `add-symbol-file foo.o <suitable-load-address>`. You could use `objcopy --add-section` to do this. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30617411/50617).

On Linux, you could also configure core dump to include read-only mappings (normally such mappings are excluded to make the `core` smaller), which would make any special steps unnecessary. See [man 5 core](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html), the section on `Controlling which mappings are written to the core dump`.

Comment: I have tried the coredump_filter solution and it works fine. I hope someone has the solution to load mapped file at analysis time. Thank a lot

Comment: @JeanChristophe I *gave* you the solution.

Comment: I can't try your second solution because my file is too big (objcopy fails). Thank for your help.