# Extracting string from ELF section in C

Tags: c, linux, elf

I have created a new ELF section and added a line of text into it. I did this following the example seen here: [Adding section to ELF file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088128/adding-section-to-elf-file). I created a section called ".mydata" and placed the string "mydata saved string" into it. I am trying to match the functionality of doing the following in the command in C:

```
$ readelf -p .mydata TEST
String dump of section '.mydata':
  [     0]    mydata saved string
```

I can find the section offset and the size of the section with the code

```
void print_item(FILE* fd, Elf64_Ehdr eh, Elf64_Shdr sh_table[])
{
    int i;
    char* sh_str;
    char* buff;

    buff = malloc(sh_table[eh.e_shstrndx].sh_size);

    if(buff != NULL)
    {
        fseek(fd, sh_table[eh.e_shstrndx].sh_offset, SEEK_SET);
        fread(buff, 1, sh_table[eh.e_shstrndx].sh_size, fd);
    }
    sh_str = buff;

    for(i=0; i<eh.e_shnum; i++)
    {
        if(!strcmp(".mydata", (sh_str + sh_table[i].sh_name)))
        {
            printf("Found section\t\".mydata\"\n");
            printf("at offset\t0x%08x\n", (unsigned int)sh_table[i].sh_offset);
            printf("of size\t\t0x%08x\n", (unsigned int)sh_table[i].sh_size);
            break;
        }
    }

/*Code to print or store string data*/
}

int main()
{
    FILE* fp = NULL; //Pointer used to access current file
    char* program_name;
    Elf64_Ehdr elf_header; //Elf header
    Elf64_Shdr* sh_table; //Elf symbol table

    program_name = "/home/Testing/TEST";
    fp = fopen(program_name, "r");

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fread(elf_header, 1, sizeof(Elf64_Ehdr), fp);
    sh_table = malloc(elf_header.e_shentsize*elf_header.e_shnum);

    print_item(fp, elf_header, sh_table);

    return 0;
}
```

Now that I have location, I am not sure the proper way to extract the string from the location. None of the ELF Section Header table entries (i.e. sh_name, sh_type ...) seem to be relevant in extracting the string.

Comment: Isn't `sh_offset` the offset of the section in the file? Add it to the offset of the symbol in the section and you should get it.

Comment: `sh_table` is `malloc`ed in `main`, never initialized, and then used in `print_item`. Either you are not showing the entire program, or your program *doesn't work at all*. Indeed the program can't possibly compile. Please edit your question with *real* code, not vague and incomplete rendition of it.

Answer (score 3):

Before we can get to your question, there are several issues with your code:

1. There are no includes.
2. `fread(elf_header,...` should be `fread(&elf_header,...`.
3. `sh_table` is never read from the ELF file.

Once those are fixed, the string data in the `.mydata` section can be read by copying `sh_table[i].sh_size` bytes of data from `sh_table[i].sh_offset` in the ELF file, where `i` is the index of the `.mydata` section.

Here is the working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <elf.h>
#include <string.h>

void print_item(FILE* fd, Elf64_Ehdr eh, Elf64_Shdr sh_table[])
{
    int i;
    char* sh_str;
    char* buff;

    buff = malloc(sh_table[eh.e_shstrndx].sh_size);

    if(buff != NULL)
    {
        fseek(fd, sh_table[eh.e_shstrndx].sh_offset, SEEK_SET);
        fread(buff, 1, sh_table[eh.e_shstrndx].sh_size, fd);
    }
    sh_str = buff;

    for(i=0; i<eh.e_shnum; i++)
    {
        if(!strcmp(".mydata", (sh_str + sh_table[i].sh_name)))
        {
            printf("Found section\t\".mydata\"\n");
            printf("at offset\t0x%08x\n", (unsigned int)sh_table[i].sh_offset);
            printf("of size\t\t0x%08x\n", (unsigned int)sh_table[i].sh_size);
            break;
        }
    }

    /*Code to print or store string data*/
    if (i < eh.e_shnum) {
        char *mydata = malloc(sh_table[i].sh_size);
        fseek(fd, sh_table[i].sh_offset, SEEK_SET);
        fread(mydata, 1, sh_table[i].sh_size, fd);
        puts(mydata);
    } else {
        // .mydata section not found
    }

}

int main()
{
    FILE* fp = NULL; //Pointer used to access current file
    char* program_name;
    Elf64_Ehdr elf_header; //Elf header
    Elf64_Shdr* sh_table; //Elf symbol table

    program_name = "/home/Testing/TEST";
    fp = fopen(program_name, "r");

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fread(&elf_header, 1, sizeof(Elf64_Ehdr), fp);
    sh_table = malloc(elf_header.e_shentsize*elf_header.e_shnum);

    fseek(fp, elf_header.e_shoff, SEEK_SET);
    fread(sh_table, 1, elf_header.e_shentsize*elf_header.e_shnum, fp);

    print_item(fp, elf_header, sh_table);

    return 0;
}
```