# Inject a .preinit_array section in an ELF file with libelf

Tags: c, linux, elf

I have the following simple `hello-world` program compiled with gcc in a standard elf binary:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void hello() {
  printf("Preinit hello!\n");
}

int main() {
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}
```

How can I create a new elf file using libelf (or any other suggested C library for such operations) in order to add a `.preinit_array` section that calls `hello()`?

My end goal is to "simulate" what a compiler would do with the following:

```c
__attribute__((section(".preinit_array"))) typeof(hello) *hello_p = hello;
```

I read `libelf by example` but I found it completely cryptic and outdated with 32-bit examples only.

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088128/adding-section-to-elf-file) related SO question. `objcopy` is doing pretty much what I would like to do but obviously I don't want to call `objcopy` from my C program. Additionally, I tried to copy `objcopy`'s source code from [here](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=binutils/objcopy.c;hb=cebd6b8ac1c5a2a847a50e3efe932ff2d0867b3e) with little success as the code is quite complicated and interconnected.

Answer (score 1):

> My end goal is to "simulate" what a compiler would do with the following

That end-goal (by itself) makes no sense to me: why not just do exactly that: add the `.preinit_array`, rebuild the program, profit.

Your *real* end-goal is probably something else (see also [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)).

The simple answer to your question is: you can't (or at least, the task is very non-trivial, and you are likely to find some other solution to your *real* problem well before you succeed with this approach).

The reason: the `ELF` file format has lots of cross-references (where parts of the file record where other parts of the file are), and the information needed to correctly update all such cross-references is discarded during the linking process.

That is, most UNIX linkers consider the `a.out` or `foo.so` the *final* product of the link, and no subsequent updates are feasible.

This isn't *entirely* true: some parts may be updated post-link, e.g. [chrpath](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/chrpath.1.html) and [patchelf](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man1/patchelf.1.html) can do such limited editing. But the general case is really difficult.

Comment: I was trying to save the readers from the details of "why" because it's a little bit irrelevant. I'm working on a research project that uses binary rewriting to intercept syscalls https://github.com/srg-imperial/SaBRe. In this project I need to load an arbitrary elf file and inject a `.preinit_array` in the headers so I can call some arbitrary symbols.