Adding custom section to PE with gcc (mingw)
I use gcc (mingw) on Windows and I want to add a custom section into the PE file similar to the way this is discussed for ELF in https://stackoverflow.com/a/30617411/1630083
But I did not find a way to add a custom section and this is what i tried so far.
attempt 1
This attempt failed in the final step with the linker:
After the linker call, my custom section .mydata, is missing but the object file still has it.
My setup is:

TDM-GCC-64 gcc 10.3.0
windows 10

And the same commands produce a valid section inside the WSL2 on Linux for ELF so I assume the commands should be working.
Here is what I did:
$ echo 'int main() { puts ("Hello world"); }' | gcc -x c - -c -o main.o

$ echo "this is my special data" >mydata

$ objcopy --add-section .mydata=mydata \
          --set-section-flags .mydata=noload,readonly main.o

$ objdump -h main.o

main.o:     file format pe-x86-64

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
  0 .text         00000020  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0000012c  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, READONLY, CODE
  1 .data         00000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000000  2**4
                  ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
  2 .bss          00000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000000  2**4
                  ALLOC
  3 .xdata        0000000c  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0000014c  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  4 .pdata        0000000c  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000158  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, READONLY, DATA
  5 .rdata$zzz    00000020  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000164  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  6 .mydata       0000001c  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000184  2**2
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, EXCLUDE

$ objdump -sj .mydata main.o

main.o:     file format pe-x86-64

Contents of section .mydata:
 0000 74686973 20697320 6d792073 70656369  this is my speci
 0010 616c2064 6174610d 0a000000           al data.....

$ gcc main.o -o main

$ objdump -h main.exe

main.exe:     file format pei-x86-64

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
  0 .text         0000b498  0000000140001000  0000000140001000  00000600  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE, DATA
  1 .data         00000100  000000014000d000  000000014000d000  0000bc00  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
  2 .rdata        00000be0  000000014000e000  000000014000e000  0000be00  2**5
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  3 .pdata        00000a80  000000014000f000  000000014000f000  0000ca00  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  4 .xdata        00000888  0000000140010000  0000000140010000  0000d600  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  5 .bss          00000390  0000000140011000  0000000140011000  00000000  2**5
                  ALLOC
  6 .idata        00000db0  0000000140012000  0000000140012000  0000e000  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
  7 .CRT          00000070  0000000140013000  0000000140013000  0000ee00  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
  8 .tls          00000010  0000000140014000  0000000140014000  0000f000  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
  9 .rsrc         000004e8  0000000140015000  0000000140015000  0000f200  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 10 .reloc        00000088  0000000140016000  0000000140016000  0000f800  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
 11 .debug_aranges 000004c0  0000000140017000  0000000140017000  0000fa00  2**4
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
 12 .debug_info   0000ade0  0000000140018000  0000000140018000  00010000  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
 13 .debug_abbrev 00001c02  0000000140023000  0000000140023000  0001ae00  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
 14 .debug_line   0000265f  0000000140025000  0000000140025000  0001cc00  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
 15 .debug_frame  00000b08  0000000140028000  0000000140028000  0001f400  2**3
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
 16 .debug_str    00000590  0000000140029000  0000000140029000  00020000  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
 17 .debug_loc    00002e16  000000014002a000  000000014002a000  00020600  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
 18 .debug_ranges 00000760  000000014002d000  000000014002d000  00023600  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING

$ objdump -sj main.exe
C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin\objdump.exe: 'a.out': No such file
C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin\objdump.exe: section 'main.exe' mentioned in a -j option, but not found in any input file

attempt 2
I also tried using these commands inside WSL2 Linux with a gcc cross compiler setup:
https://chatgpt.com/share/54b290c4-6a12-45e9-b507-f64ca2283647
But I noticed that this call:
gcc -o my_program.exe my_program.o -Wl,-T,custom.ld

Will work if the custom.ld and default.ld are correctly edited but the custom.ld is never mentioned in the collect2.exe call which can be seen when using -v at the end of the gcc command.
As a result it will never use the custom.ld and thus my own sections are never added either. Not tested for ELF, only for PE.
attempt 3
I was also looking into modifying gcc/binutils but didn't know exactly where to start.
My main goal is to add/append a section called '.inStore' which holds 100 bytes of data and is generated after the '.idata' entry is completely generated.
My goal is to understand from which source code the .idata section is generated. I want to modify the dllname, i.e. 'libstdc++-6.dll', string with adding a huge empty space so that i later can change it into a different name without relocations.
I was reading:
https://chatgpt.com/share/9efed972-0c90-4c5f-9660-30132984d9d6
Binutils - GNU Linker (ld)

ld/pe-dll.c / ld/pe-dll.h

https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/binutils/+/refs/heads/binutils-2_27-branch/ld/pe-dll.c

For attempt 1 I managed to add a custom section using only:  'objcopy --add-section .mydata=mydata main.o' AND leaving out the part with '--set-section-flags .mydata=noload,readonly'. Then the final main.exe will have the .mydata section!

For attempt 2 I managed to add a custom section using only: 'echo 'int main() { puts ("Hello world"); }' | gcc -x c - -c -o main.o' AND gcc -Xlinker -T./default.ld main.o -o main.exe -> ./main.exe -> Hello world -> and default.ld was created using ld --verbose and adding   .foo BLOCK(section_alignment) :
{
LONG (0); LONG (0); LONG (0); LONG (0); LONG (0);
}

For attempt 3 I managed to hack on lld (LLVM) instead of ld (binutils) and got pretty far. The compiler now creates the section I wanted: https://github.com/nixcloud/fixPath/
